# Using a Snow Leopard disk image (clone) on a Tiger Computer

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, clone, osx-tiger

I've got a computer running Tiger that is becoming unbearably slow, pinwheeling at the slightest activity. I've tried to create a backup using Super Duper and it won't even create one due to the i/o error and the disk having too many errors. So I rebuilt the disk with Diskwarrior, still no go on the backup. Tried Carbon Copy Cloner and it just froze. SMART status is still verified amazingly enough. Even tried all this in safe mode, and it still doesn't work, though the drive is quicker in safe mode.

**So bottom line. I have an external with a clone from a Snow Leopard computer. Is there any chance that it would work if I just booted from it and replaced the Tiger portion of the disk with the Snow Leopard clone?**

The Tiger computer has an Intel processor btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the SMART output, your internal disk appears to be failing. Replacing the OS on the disk probably won't solve your problem. It sounds like it's time for a new hard drive.

However, if you'd like to try to boot off the external disk, you can do this by holding down the option key when you turn on the computer. Then select the external drive. Or you can go to System Preferences and choose Startup Disk to use the external drive.

Good luck!